# Length of 3D Vector - Square root rules

Tags: vectors

I have a 3D vector $r(u)=(16u^3,0,16)$, which I want to find the length of. I do this by $|r(u)|=\sqrt{(16u^3)^2+16^2}$

Could someone explain how $\sqrt{(16u^3)^2+16^2}$ yields $16 \sqrt{u^6+1}$?

Thanks

Comment: Distribute the square and factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$$

when $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: $a, b$ should not be negative ...

Comment: You're right, thank you!

Comment: Yes, I'm familar with than one, but I get confused when we have $\sqrt{ab+c}$

Comment: Are there any common factors under the square root?